# What is the meaning of "ardent learner"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, learning

Actually I was searching title for website ( which is indirectly for me ;) ), so I've come up with word "ardent" (of course by googling) but i'm bit confused about this word "ardent".

`Is it positive/negative?`

`Is it suitable to write in resume like things also?`

`What does "ardent learner" actually means?`

What I understand is that : "ardent means VERY much in something" > so meaning of given statement that I think is "very much learner" or kind of "knowledge seeker"

Please give your answers(reviews) about it and always thanks in advance.

Remark: I've searched different dictionaries, used translate.google.com and many things about this, and may be that's why I'm confused.

Comment: Ardent learner means someone who is passionate / enthusiastic about learning.

Comment: It's not clear what is unclear to you regarding the dictionary definition (which you mention but do not cite). Does it help to learn that *ardent* comes from "**burning**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't normally go with Google's definitions, but I like theirs better than MW's in this case.  Google defines it as "enthusiastic or passionate", such as "an ardent baseball fan".  They also list some additional synonyms such as zealous, fervent, and intense.

If you say you're an ardent learner then you're saying that you're enthusiastic about learning.  You're probably self-motivated, and very interested in knowing as much as you can.  "Knowledge seeker" is accurate (though "very much learner" is ungrammatical*).  There's absolutely nothing wrong with putting "ardent learner" on a resume; it's a good "fluff" word that describes positive qualities.

That said, I'd be afraid to put *any* word on my resume if I'm not very familiar with it -- it might come back to haunt me in a follow-up question during an in-person interview!  (Disclaimer:  I'm overly cautious about such things)

Comment: thanks for clarification; yes i too know about wording in resume, thats why i asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

Ardent means passionate, eager, or having intense feelings about something.

There are both positive and negative connotations. Its uses are all related to strong feelings or intensity, and many things taken to an extreme are considered excessive.

For example, it can mean passion bordering on zealotry, which has a negative connotation: "ardent supporters of the bill were willing to do *anything* to see it succeed".

It can also mean devoted or enthusiastic, both of which have positive connotations.

[Dictionary.com definitions](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ardent):

> 1. having, expressive of, or characterized by intense feeling; passionate; fervent
> 2. intensely devoted, eager, or enthusiastic; zealous
> 3. vehement; fierce
> 4. burning, fiery, or hot:

The synonym guide on the [Merriam-Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ardent) page is helpful for exploring the connotations.

Regarding use on a resume: I would confirm on workplace stack exchange, but it seems excessive and somewhat pretentious to say " ardent learner" on a resume.